# Unable to install landscape 19.10

Tags: apt, server, updates, ppa, landscape

I have an Ubuntu server VM running 18.04 on Proxmox 6.1-7 that I am unable to install [Landscape 19.10](https://docs.ubuntu.com/landscape/en/) on. I follow the steps from the [on prem setup page](https://landscape.canonical.com/set-up-on-prem). I have tried with both the `--update` flag and without. The following code snippet is what Is returned when trying the first step:

```
username@landscape:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:landscape/19.10
 October 2019 release of Landscape
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~landscape/+archive/ubuntu/19.10
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                  
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Ign:2 https://ppa.launchpad.net/landscape/19.10/ubuntu bionic InRelease      
Err:6 https://ppa.launchpad.net/landscape/19.10/ubuntu bionic Release        
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown. The name in the certificate does not match the expected.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 91.189.95.83 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/landscape/19.10/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

As you can see it runs into an issue with adding the PPA, citing a certificate issue during the process. If I attempt the next step to install with the command `sudo apt install landscape-server-quickstart`, I get the following:

```
username@landscape:~$ sudo apt install landscape-server-quickstart
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package landscape-server-quickstart
```

If I attempt to go to the url for the package, `https://ppa.launchpad.net/landscape/19.10/ubuntu bionic`, I am greeted by a certificate error.

#### closing notes

The server and hypervisor are up to date, both apt and snaps. I have no proxy or IDP/IPS to interrupt the traffic. Is there something I am missing here? Is the certificate bad? Is there a different guide I should follow?

Answer (score 2):

> Err:6 https://ppa.launchpad.net/landscape/19.10/ubuntu bionic Release

PPA are accessible through clear http. Exception is for private-PPA which require authentication, but this isn't one of those. Also private PPAs are served from https://private-ppa.launchpad.net, thus likely explaining the SSL error you're getting.

I suggest to:

1. remove those https ppa entries
2. re-run `sudo add-apt-repository --update ppa:landscape/19.10` so it can add back the ppa (as http, not https) and import the GPG signing key, if that hasn't been done.

Comment: Thank you for your response! How do I import the GPG key?

Comment: Normally, add-apt-repository does it for you. When you add a source manually (say by editing the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, you can import a key using apt-key. For this PPA, fetching it would look like `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys  6E85A86E4652B4E6` , where the last argument  corresponds to the fingerprint of the key (or its last digits)

Answer (score 1):

Add the next record to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` manually:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/landscape/19.10/ubuntu bionic main
```

Then

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install landscape-server-quickstart
```

[Source](https://launchpad.net/~landscape/+archive/ubuntu/19.10)

[image: landscape bionic repository]

Comment: No dice, I still get the cert issues with this. I've added both the one line and tried with both lines to my sources list. I get the same cert issue/release file missing thing I posted earlier.

Comment: have you removed previous source from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`?

Comment: Yep, I have nothing in there for landscape. I restored to a previous snapshot of when the server was fully up to date and nothing else was installed. I get the same error.