# 21.10 sudo apt update failing

Tags: hplip, 21.10

After doing `sudo apt update` receiving following:

```
Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The name in the certificate does not match the expected.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 2a01:4280:2:211a::70 443]
Err:2 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease...I added the tag HPLIP because this all started after purchasing an HP allin one printer, and it has proven impossible install, run, and connect to my laptop. To my phone, yes, and I should have been satisfied with just that.   so, at this point, after powering down and rebooting, doing sudo apt update, this is where I am at...   Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rock-core/qt4/ubuntu impish InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease          
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease [99.5 kB]    
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rock-core/qt4/ubuntu impish Release             
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::19 80]
Ign:5 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease                    
Ign:5 https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease                    
0% [Working]
```

...and now nothing is happening

I have turned off the computer, and I turned it back on. I went to 'software updater' and received the following message:
Failed to download repsoitory information.
and...
Failed to download package files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to install landscape 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1215398/unable-to-install-landscape-19-10)

Comment: That mirror does not currently provide a secure https connection. Use http instead, or use a different mirror. The system is designed to be secure (each package is signed) without https.

Comment: you tagged hplip - why? Please [edit] your question with further details. What were you updating from and what steps were taken for the update?

Comment: Sorry, am really lost here. The whole problem started when I  tried to run HPLIP. I ended up installing Python 3.10. Then when I tried to run I received a message: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distro', so in search of this I have totally lost a functionable upgrade,  The upgrade currently shows a string of message as the following; E: Failed to fetch https://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/util-linux/rfkill_2.36.1-8ubuntu2_amd64.deb  Certificate verification failed: The certific...on and on, excuse me, but as I said I am lost,

Comment: rebooting, restarting, sudo apt update...nothing!

Comment: Please change to main server. when I open the side in firefox I get an unsecure certificate warning for htttps.

Comment: the answer is here...https://askubuntu.com/a/141772/1495660

Comment: the mirror was not providing a secure https connection, thankyou! - user535733

Comment: Delete that broken PPA while you are editing your sources.

Comment: Seems like a transient error, should be resolved by now.

Comment: installed software sources from unity dash, does not launch on ubuntu 21.10, so I am unable to delete the broken PPA, still showing this in sudo apt update...

Answer (score 0):

The error message occurs because that mirror does not currently provide a secure (https) connection.

**Solution**: Edit your sources to use http instead, or select a different mirror.

- Note that the rest of the sources in your output are NOT https.

**Explanation**: The use of https is optional. The system is designed to be secure without https. Ubuntu does not control mirrors (they are volunteers), and Ubuntu cannot provide SSL certificates to servers that it does not control. So most mirrors do NOT offer https. Instead, each package is signed, and apt tests each signature automatically.